# How to start a peer with backup data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The ledger data is stored in this path `/var/hyperledger/production/` inside the peer's container, as said in this description: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3364.

How can one use this backup data to start a peer from scratch with predefined data?
This jira item does have a description on how to do it, but it has almost no detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just set the environment variable to look to the ledger path that you want. So if you have a shell script that sets some variables, let's say setEnv.sh you can add:

```
export CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=<Your ledger's path>
```

Then you can run that file and source it with a dot in front like: `. ./setEnv.sh`

If you don't wanna use shell scripts you can just do in the terminal:

```
source CORE_PEER_FILESYSTEMPATH=<Your ledger's path>
```